# Enabling cURL with PHP

Tags: php, curl

(I'm running Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.4.14)

I'm having problems enabling cURL with PHP. I uncommented the `extension=php_curl.dll` line in php.ini and made sure that the dependencies `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` exist in the path.  I also restarted Apache.  However, when I run phpinfo() I do not see a cURL header and trying to call a cURL function results in the following error: 
`Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\boxproject\php\lib\Box_Rest_Client.php on line 114`

Does anyone see any problems with this process? Are there more ways to troubleshoot the problem?  Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: sure you're modifying the correct php.ini? there's usually two: one for command line and one for SAPI (web-server).

Comment: Yep, double checked after I saw your comment and I'm 99% sure I modified the right file.  There's only one php.ini file in my installation path.

Comment: Did you check the apache log file? ( "wamp/logs/apache_error.log" if your install has been made with wamp).

Comment: I installed Apache and PHP individually but here is the log: `[Mon May 06 10:36:06 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Apache Software Foundation\\Apache2.2\\htdocs\\boxproject\\get_access_token.php on line 16`

Comment: No message (in the logs and linked to curl) is displayed while Apache is restarting?

Comment: Ahh.  I overlooked the messages that displayed when Apache was restarting.  I get the following line during restart: `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\Users\\jauhar.basrai\\My Programs\\php\\ext\\php_curl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0`.  I'm not sure why this error would show though, I see the php_curl.dll file in php\ext.  Looks like we're on to something though, thanks a lot for the help so far!!

Comment: You need to download a php_curl.dll which has been compiled on the same OS as you and for the php 5.4.14.

Comment: Hm. I've downloaded php5.4.14's php_curl.dll from several sources now, but using those still doesn't fix the problem.  I'm not sure that the problem is with the dll file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Uncomment the php_curl.dll from php.ini

Step2: Copy the following three files from php installed directory to the bin directory of Apache

libeay32.dll, libssh2.dll, ssleay32.dll

Step3: Restart apache.