# PHP curl and Apache fcgid conflict

Tags: php, windows, apache, curl, mod-fcgid

I'm having a sort of odd issue with *PHP 5.3.9, Apache 2.4 on Windows 7 x64*.  
I use FastCGI 2.3.9 for Apache 2.4 (both are compiled with VC11) to fork my virtual hosts between *PHP 5.6.18* and *PHP 5.3.9.*  
The issue is that when I enable curl in the config of *PHP 5.3.9*, every page of every virtual host which uses this PHP version starts showing

> Error 500 (Internal server error).

Apache error log said the following after I've opened [Example Link](http://example.com/index.php) page:

```
[fcgid:warn] [pid 6720:tid 1528] (OS 109)The pipe has been ended.  :     [client 198.101.238.203:62561] mod_fcgid: get overlap result error
[core:error] [pid 6720:tid 1528] [client 198.101.238.203:62561] End of script output before headers: index.php
```

When I disable curl, the error disappears. Though, I need this module to make the **CMS** I need to install on this server to work.
Since I am using Windows (sadly), installing PHP-FPM is not something I can allow myself (but if you know any way to install it under Win7 x64, please tell me).
Please share me any ideas on how this issue can be solved. How to make fcgid and curl friends? :)
Thanks for your answers and efforts!

Comment: could be a dependency issue.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/30811161/3504007

Comment: I've tried that one, still getting same error 500. Curious, but when I only enabled libssh2, it also threw me error 500.

Comment: If it helps, I have the php execulable and runtimes all inside the same folder as apache, and the modules are located in a subfolder within that path.

Comment: The situation gets more complicated just because of different PHP versions on a server. Repeating that, I am using fcgid to fork PHP versions for making some websites work correctly.

Comment: have you tried running this version of php as the apache module directly ?  i havn't setup multiple php versions running on any system as the entire process of it seems a bit wonky.