# XAMPP Solr PHP PECL

Tags: php, solr, xampp, pecl

I am trying to install the [PHP PECL Solr extension](https://pecl.php.net/package/solr/2.4.0/windows) on XAMPP running on Windows.  I have gotten the right DLL for my PHP version, and ensured that it's in the correct directory for extensions as indicated in php.ini, and added the extension to php.ini.

When I start XAMPP it says it "Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_solr.dll' - the specified module could not be found."  I'm not sure if it's talking about the .dll because it's there.  I don't know if any other files in the zip belong in the ..\ext folder too.  The only thing that's in there besides READMEs and .php files is php_solr.pdb.  Tried dropping that into ..\ext but that didn't help.  The README says refer to README.INSTALLATION but there is no such file in the zip.  What to do?

Comment: file permissions?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424117/php-unable-to-load-php-curl-dll-extension)

It's the same reason, that `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` have to be path-accessible for `php_solr.dll` loading to succeed
So put your `C:\xampp\php` into system path and it should work

Comment: php
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'solr' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\solr (The specified module could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_solr.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
I have 

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'solr' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\solr (The specified module could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_solr.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0