# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_curl.dll'

Tags: php-7.2, uwamp

For a project I need die php_curl.dll Module.
I activated the model at all php.ini files. 
But I get a PHP Warning, that the modul is unable to load. 
By check of the error.log file, is see this information:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_curl.dll' (tried: …/UwAmp/bin/php/php-7.2.4/ext\php_curl.dll

What I can do, that the path is correct loading or generated ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP unable to load php\_curl.dll extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424117/php-unable-to-load-php-curl-dll-extension)

Answer (score 0):

libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll have to be path-accessible for php_curl.dll loading to succeed. So, open the php folder inside your UwAmp installation and copy the files to:

bin/apache/bin/

Then restart UwAmp. See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's something wrong with the PHP 7.2.5 installation zip (php-7.2.5-Win32-VC15-x64.zip) maybe it's the same with the 7.2.4, there are no `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` libraries included which are obviously needed by the curl library module.

My solution was to install the 7.1.17 version where the files where included and copy those dll's to Apache bin's directory. It should be enough, if not try also to include PHP (in my case `c:\usr\php71`) and Apache bin (in my case `c:\usr\Apache24\bin`) directory to you PATH variable.. and restart Windows to be safe.