# EasyPHP Devserver 17: The program can't be start because is libssh2.dll is missing

Tags: php, easyphp, devserver

I'm new in PHP development.
I was using Easyphp old version, now I upgraded to the new one but now an alert error message `the program can't be start because is libssh2.dll missing.` is displaying when trying to open it or when I enable `cURL` function.
I reinstalled the software but it's still not working. If I disable `extension=php_curl.dll` in `php.ini` then it's fine, but `cURL` is not working anymore.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmIaA.jpg)

What should I do? I tried everything, I wasted 3 nights.
Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i also got this message when i started to use curl with EasyPHP-Devserver 17 and i follow these steps which actually solved the issue:

try to download the DLL from a secure website ,you can use this link :
http://www.dll-found.com/download/l/libssh2.dll

then follow the steps:

- Free Download libssh2.dll to your computer.
- move the dll file to the system directory.    (Windows XP, Vista,
  Windows 7) - C:\Windows\System32 (Windows    NT/2000) -
  C:\WINNT\System32 (Windows 95/98/Me) - C:\Windows\System    If you
  use a 64 bit version of Windows, The System Directory in
  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
- Reboot computer.

You can also simply copy the libssh2.dll file into the PHP  directory which must look like

> C:\Program
>   Files\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\php\php713vc14x86x171216121038

for PHP7

and

> C:\Program
>   Files\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\php\php5630vc11x86x171216121038

for PHP 5.6

Comment: Don't forget to restart the server or reboot the computer @Rahul Kumar.

Comment: can u tell me how to change its port number to 786 rather than its predefined ports like 8000,8080 etc

Comment: @Rahul Kumar you must look into the ini file and change the default port. Can you mark my answer as the solution as it works for you?it may help other to know that the issue has been solved.

Comment: @Rahul Kumar you must look into the ini file and change the default port. Can you mark my answer as the solution as it works for you?it may help other to know that the issue has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a much cleaner solution from stackoverflow:

[PHP unable to load php_curl.dll extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26368386/4589628)

I had to reboot my windows 7 to get the changed path recognized by apache.