# Call to undefined function curl_init() php 7.2.34

Tags: php, php-curl

I know this question has been asked before, but none of the answer given helped me...

The extension line in the php.ini is uncommented `extension=php_curl.dll`

I recently updated GLPI to the last version (9.5.2, was in 9.3.1 before) so I had to change php version from 7.1.9 to 7.2.34.

It's on a WS2012R2 64bits, Wamp 3.1.0 32bits, so I put php in 32bits too.

I checked dependencies with doing "deplister.exe ext\php_curl.dll" and all is "OK" now (a few dll were missing, I copied them from another php version).

I have tried :

- reboot the server (at least once)
- restart wamp (at least once)

Do you have any idea on how to solve this ?

I can have a look at any solutions

[EDIT] solution is in comments : this was solved downgrading php from 7.2.34 to 7.2.10

Comment: Are there multiple copies of php.ini on your system? Are you sure you modified the correct copy?

Comment: There are, but each of them have the extension uncommented.
I looked which one was used by apache, and it's the good one, `phpForApache.ini` in the php7.2.34 folder

Comment: Adding a few info : when running `php -v` in CMD, I have a `Cannot find rc_dtor_func@@4 in php7.2.34\ext\php_curl.dll`, followed in CMD by `Unable to load library 'prp_curl.dll'`

Comment: Did you tried this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424117/php-unable-to-load-php-curl-dll-extension

Comment: That's weird ... your link talk about `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` but I don't see them in the `deplister.exe` result... 
And yes, I have the php folder in the PATH : `C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.2.34`.
I just saw that both missing dlls are in another php folder, I'll try copy them, or download them.
I'll tell you if it works

Comment: I tried a few things, it seems that both `*eay32.dll` files are not required anymore.
Also, when I delete the `libcrypto-1_1.dll` and `libssl-1_1.dll` files in apache\bin, apache doesn't start.

Comment: I seems the main problem is php 7.2.34. The issue was solved by downgrading php to 7.2.10

Comment: for future reference, in php.ini set `display_errors=1` and `display_startup_errors=1` , then run the curl_init() code, and check the webserver error logs, the error logs should tell you why curl failed to load.